# SQL Server - Sum of difference between rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, window-functions

I have a table in the format :

```
SomeID  SomeData

1       3
2       7
3       9
4       10
5       14
6       16
.       .
.       .
```

I want to find sum of difference between rows in this table. i.e `( (7-3)  + (10-9) + (16-14) + ....)`

Which is the best way to do this

Comment: What's your dbms? `sqlserver!=oracle`

Comment: Why those row pairs?  Why not  `(3-7)` or `(14-10)` or `(16-9)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a self join along with the modulus:

```sql
SELECT SUM(t1.SomeData - t2.SomeData) AS total_diff
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.SomeID = t2.SomeID + 1
WHERE t1.SomeID % 2 = 0;
```

### Demo

This answer assumes that the `SomeID` sequence in fact starts with 1 and increments by 1 with each subsequent row.  If not, then we might be able to first apply `ROW_NUMBER` over `SomeID` and generate a 1 to N sequence.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeID) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT SUM(t1.SomeData - t2.SomeData) AS total_diff
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.SomeID = t2.SomeID + 1
WHERE t1.rn % 2 = 0;
```

Comment: Can you share query if someID not in sequence

Comment: Do you still make the assumption that `SomeID` provides the ordering of the records?

Comment: By not in sequence, i was referring to it can contain any values but @TimBiegeleisen already helped in achieving it by using ROW_Number

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to make a serial number then MOD by 2 to get your expected group then use condition aggregate function.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN SomeData END) - SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN SomeData END) 
FROM (
  SELECT SomeData,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by SomeID) % 2 rn
  FROM t t1
) t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0286/7/0)**:

```
|   |
|---|
| 7 |
```